# VMs keep disappearing from vmplayer on reboot

Tags: vmware

My VMs in both /home and other places keep disappearing after reboot. I'm running vmplayer 6.0.1 and ubuntu 12.04. Ive tried removing .vmware under /home but the problem persists.

```
saad@beast:~$ ls -l /home/saad/.vmware
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saad saad  426 Feb  6 10:23 player.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saad saad 1114 Feb  6 10:13 playerUploadedData.log
-rw------- 1 saad saad  301 Feb  6 10:23 preferences
```

Comment: Assuming the file is under **home** directory, could you please [**edit**](http://askubuntu.com/posts/417087/edit) your question and post the output of `ls -l /home/.vmware` please.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this will help butcould you please have a look at [**How to save vmware player library?**](http://askubuntu.com/q/75328/179042)

Comment: i'll try the workaround script

Answer (score 0):

I also have problems with a disappearing library. It is most likely related to the ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel file that contains a list of recently used files.

```
henning@henning-T60:~/.local/share$ ls -la recently-used.xbel 
-rw------- 1 henning henning 1385 mars  23 09:27 recently-used.xbel
```

Some times (and I don't do exactly why) *the owner and group of the file changes from henning to root.* 
Manually starting

```
 vmplayer
```

will then complain about failed access to recently-used.xbel file.

Assuming that the reference to the vm is still in the recently-used.xbel file,
it should work to regain own access to the file with

```
sudo chown henning: recently-used.xbel
```

I've tried to using inotify-interface watch access to the file with

```
inotifywait -m ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

which normally gives on startup:

```
henning@henning-T60:~/.local/share$ inotifywait -m recently-used.xbel 
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
recently-used.xbel OPEN 
recently-used.xbel ACCESS 
recently-used.xbel CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE
```

and on close of vmplayer gives:

```
recently-used.xbel ATTRIB 
recently-used.xbel DELETE_SELF
```

So the file's attributes are changed and the file deleted, but somehow recreated again because it's still in the directory afterwards.

Using strace on the start of vmplayer to test.log

```
henning@henning-T60:~/.local/share$ sudo strace -e trace=file -o test.log  vmplayer
```

and then

```
 henning@henning-T60:~/.local/share$ more test.log | grep 'recently-used'
  access("/home/henning/.recently-used.xbel", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
  open("/home/henning/.local/share/recently-used.xbel", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 7
  open("/home/henning/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.XVW5CX", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 23
  lstat64("/home/henning/.local/share/recently-used.xbel", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=218, ...}) = 0
  rename("/home/henning/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.XVW5CX", "/home/henning/.local/share/recently-used.xbel") = 0
  chmod("/home/henning/.local/share/recently-used.xbel", 0600) = 0
```

So a new file recently-used.xbel.XVW5CX is created and later renamed to recently-used.xbel

Answer (score 0):

I was was using Ubuntu Version 16 and vmwareworkstatin 12

Best way to fix this issue is to do the Following:

open your Terminal and go to Home Dir or /home/userid

Now inside Home/Userid
Create a new folder " mkdir VMware_Temp "

Then copy everything from your existing Folder /home/userid/vmware
to the new VMware_Temp Dir

Now here is the fix:
from the command prompt or Shell prompt run this simple command:
As we need to delete the .vmware folder as its corrupt now. 
" sudo rm -r $HOME/.vmware "

Then go back to your GUI or Desktop on Ubuntu and Open back up VMware Workstation.
and Just Create a Virtual Machine and Select I will install Operating System Later.

Now you should see your new VM you just created.
so close Vmware workstation and Reopen vmwareworkstation again to see if the new VM is still there if So!

Go back to your Folder you created VMware_Temp and THEN Cut and Paste Back everything again inside the folder again /Home/userid/vmware

Then from Within VMware workstation do a File>Open> 
/Home/Userid/vmware/"vmware folder name" 
for virtual machine you want to run.

Now do the above for each virtual machine you have installed inside vmware folder.

Then Close your VMware Workstation and Reopen
Now Then!   You should be seeing all your Virtual Machines you have created listed

Have Fun!

you need to remove the .VMware Folder like so.

Don